# How to disable creation of multiple users option completely?

Tags: multi-user, google-pixel-6a

I'm looking to disable the option for creating more than one user on my Pixel 6a phone (running Calyx OS).

The standard way to do it seems to be [this](https://www.droidviews.com/remove-guest-account-feature-on-android/). However, this requires TWRP which is [not available](https://twrp.me/Devices/) for Pixel 6a. Alternately, The BuildProp editor app that they recommend is no longer available on the Play Store.

Is there a way around these limitations?

Comment: On recent systems editing a file like `/system/build.prop` on main/system partition doesn't work anymore. Using magisk and modules it is possible to let the system load different properties. See e.g. https://github.com/Magisk-Modules-Repo/MagiskHidePropsConf

Comment: You can try this module [Disables the multiple users feature in Android](https://github.com/d3rt0xx/magisk-single-user-mod).  I never needed to so haven't used it

Comment: @beeshyams this link doesn't have a readme so I'm not sure what it does. I don't have the technical know how to parse a script that deals with android backend

Comment: I just tried it , it works on stock ROM . From settings tapping *Add user or profile* or *add guest* does not act. Nothing happens unlike before when you could create a user. It works on stock . With your ROM, only you can confirm

Comment: I just tried this, after I boot into recovery mode and try the command `adb pull /system/build.prop` as per the instructions, I get an error `adb: error: failed to get feature set: no devices/emulators found`. So I guess the adb is not detected?

Comment: Recovery mode is quite different from TWRP mode which is like a scaled down OS. Method meant for TWRP mode will not work for recovery mode//Also read the first comment made by @Robert //Lastly, I told you the Magisk module works on your model. Trying that on your ROM is the easiest way IMO //It's good to experiment but you should know the difference between TWRP and stock recovery

Comment: thanks for that advice. I will try this out. I'm just a bit vary of doing something I don't understand

Comment: Unless you tag me @myname_here, I will not be notified